# Redirect http to https only in one page and the others pages https to http

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I want redirect some pages from http to https (The pages with forms and login page) and the others pages, https to http.

How I do without write all rules for every page?

Comment: It's not secure to only protect the login page if the authentification cookie is accessible to http webpage. The only secure way to manage a website with authentication form is with https everywhere and hsts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following  in /root.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect /login from http => https#
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#redirect any other request excluding /login from https to http#
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^login http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```